# Implementing a turnstile-like operator with RxJava

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I need help implementing a turnstile-like operator in RxJava (RxScala). I spent quite some time thinking about it, but I seem to be stuck.

The type of the function should be the following:

```
def turnstile[T](queue: Observable[T], turnstile: Observable[Boolean]): Observable[T]
```

The idea is that the behavior of the operator should be very similar to a real turnstile. There are people coming (`queue`), and there is a `turnstile` that is either ready for accepting new **single** person (a `true` element in the turnstile, you can imagine it as a token inserted into the turnstile), or closed (`false` in the turnstile, canceling previous token). For every `true` element in the turnstile, only one person may pass.

Furthermore, inserting several tokens in a row (several `true` items in a turnstile) without a person passing is the same as inserting only a single token, the turnstile doesn't count the tokens.

In other words, the turnstile is initially closed. When a `true` element appears in it, it opens up for a single person. If a person appears, it passes through (to the output) and the turnstile closes again. If a `false` element appears in the turnstile, the turnstile also closes.

```
queue       ----A---B-------------C--D--
turnstile   --T--------T--T-T-T-T------T
            ============================
output      ----A------B----------C----D
```

*A marble diagram showing open turnstile waiting for a person A, then person B waiting for the turnstile to open,then several tokens behaving as one - person C passes, but person D has to wait for a new token again*

```
----A----B--
--T---T-F-T-
============
----A-----B-
```

*A marble diagram showing, how a `false` element in the turnstile closes the turnstile again.*

Any help is appreciated. I think the only way to implement this without writing a custom operator would be using the `zip` operator somehow, because it is probably the only operator that makes elements from one sequence wait for elements from the other (or are there any others I'm not aware of?). But I need to *not* zip some of the turnstile elements depending on whether they got paired with a person or not...

I think this is an interesting problem, and I'm quite curious about some nice solution to it.

Comment: Have you looked at [and-then-when](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Combining-Observables#and-then-and-when) operators, combined with perhaps [distinct](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Filtering-Observables#distinct)?

Comment: @AdamS The documentation is scarce, but it seems to me to be just an alternative syntax for `zip` that also allows `zip` with arity > 2 (which RxJava already allows). Or am I mistaken? Can you elaborate on how would that help solve my problem, please?

Comment: I think perhaps I misunderstood their meaning during my cursory glance at these functions - you appear to be quite right. Interesting question, though. I'll keep thinking about it.

Comment: See [this Rx.NET GIST](https://gist.github.com/RxDave/9adc25455917ff12b9b8). It relies on Rx's async iterator overload of `Create`, which uses .NET's `Task<T>` to allow the user to define a coroutine that acts as a state machine. In a previous experimental version of Rx.NET (1.1), there was an alternative `Create` overload using `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `Task<T>`, before coroutines were introduced in C# 5.0. Alternatively, you could also do something similar just using the `Scan` operator, which is essentially like a *running aggregation*. Perhaps someone who knows RxJava can convert it.

Comment: By the way, `And`, `Then` and `When` implement [Join Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join-pattern).

Comment: @Dave I have just posted an answer using your state machine suggestion. Thank you for the inspiration, it made me stop about `zip` all the time. As for the `And, Then, When`, thank you for the link, but I'll need to ponder about it for quite some time. In essence, just to kickstart me, is there something you can achieve with the triad that you can't with just `zip` and `merge`, or not? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know of anyone that has used Join Patterns in production. It's more than `Zip` when you specify multiple join patterns at the same time. Notice that `When` accepts more than one pattern. [Here's one example](https://twitter.com/headinthebox/status/281529041847209984) and an [older example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3ca3a0d4-ac61-4325-9fa2-ed622830b518/join-patterns-in-rx?forum=rx) both written by the man himself, Erik Meijer. And here's [one more example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2009/11/18/reactive-extensions-for-net-rx.aspx).

Comment: Perhaps Join Patterns should be thought of as *joined and filtered zips*, in the sense that you specify multiple zips and the `When` operator filters for the patterns that match the inputs. I'm no expert on Join Patterns though. :-)

Comment: @Dave Thank you for all the links. Btw, I just started reading your blog, and it's great stuff. I've always suspected there is something rotten with the definition of Hot and Cold observables,  and your take on it (has/has not side effects on subscription) makes so much more sense :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think I have a cleaner, fully Rx solution. This was actually a pretty fun problem to solve. Provided it works for your needs, I think it ended up being really elegant, although it took quite awhile to arrive at it.

Sadly I don't know Scala, so you're going to have to deal with my Java8 lambdas. :D

The entire implementation:

```
public static Observable<String> getTurnstile(final Observable<String> queue, final Observable<Boolean> tokens) {
    return queue.publish(sharedQueue ->
            tokens.switchMap(token -> token ? sharedQueue.limit(1) : Observable.empty()));
}
```

So, what's happening here is we use `publish` to make a shared observable of the people queue that we can subscribe to multiple times. Inside that, we use a `switchMap` on our token stream, which means any time a new Observable is emitted from the switchMap, it drops the last one and subscribes to the new one. Any time a token is true, it makes a new subscription to the people queue (and multiple trues in a row is fine, because it's canceling the old subscriptions). When it's false, it just dumps out an empty Observable to not waste time.

And some (passing) testcases:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class TurnstileTest {
    private final TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    private final TestSubscriber<String> output = new TestSubscriber<>();

    private final TestSubject<Boolean> tokens = TestSubject.create(scheduler);
    private final TestSubject<String> queue = TestSubject.create(scheduler);

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Turnstile.getTurnstile(queue, tokens).subscribe(output);
    }

    @Test
    public void allowsOneWithTokenBefore() {
        tokens.onNext(true, 0);
        queue.onNext("Bill", 1);
        queue.onNext("Bob", 2);

        assertPassedThrough("Bill");
    }

    @Test
    public void tokenBeforeIsCancelable() {
        tokens.onNext(true, 0);
        tokens.onNext(false, 1);
        queue.onNext("Bill", 2);

        assertNonePassed();
    }

    @Test
    public void tokensBeforeAreCancelable() {
        tokens.onNext(true, 0);
        tokens.onNext(true, 1);
        tokens.onNext(true, 2);
        tokens.onNext(false, 3);
        queue.onNext("Bill", 4);

        assertNonePassed();
    }

    @Test
    public void eventualPassThroughAfterFalseTokens() {
        tokens.onNext(false, 0);
        queue.onNext("Bill", 1);
        tokens.onNext(false, 2);
        tokens.onNext(false, 3);
        queue.onNext("Jane", 4);
        queue.onNext("Bob", 5);
        tokens.onNext(true, 6);
        tokens.onNext(true, 7);
        tokens.onNext(false, 8);
        tokens.onNext(false, 9);
        queue.onNext("Phil", 10);
        tokens.onNext(false, 11);
        tokens.onNext(false, 12);
        tokens.onNext(true, 13);

        assertPassedThrough("Bill", "Jane", "Bob");
    }

    @Test
    public void allowsOneWithTokenAfter() {
        queue.onNext("Bill", 0);
        tokens.onNext(true, 1);
        queue.onNext("Bob", 2);

        assertPassedThrough("Bill");
    }

    @Test
    public void multipleTokenEntriesBeforeOnlyAllowsOneAtATime() {
        tokens.onNext(true, 0);
        tokens.onNext(true, 1);
        tokens.onNext(true, 2);
        queue.onNext("Bill", 3);
        tokens.onNext(true, 4);
        tokens.onNext(true, 5);
        queue.onNext("Jane", 6);
        queue.onNext("John", 7);

        assertPassedThrough("Bill", "Jane");
    }

    @Test
    public void noneShallPassWithoutToken() {
        queue.onNext("Jane", 0);
        queue.onNext("John", 1);

        assertNonePassed();
    }

    private void closeSubjects() {
        scheduler.advanceTimeBy(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        scheduler.triggerActions();
        tokens.onCompleted();
        queue.onCompleted();
        scheduler.triggerActions();
    }

    private void assertNonePassed() {
        closeSubjects();
        output.assertReceivedOnNext(Lists.newArrayList());
    }

    private void assertPassedThrough(final String... names) {
        closeSubjects();
        output.assertReceivedOnNext(Lists.newArrayList(names));
    }
}
```

Let me know if you find any edge cases that don't work with this, particularly if it has trouble in real time since the tests are obviously in a controlled environment.

Comment: Yes, it indeed does work, does pass my test, and is a nice solution (so simple, in retrospect :). The scala version of it is `queue.publish(sharedQueue ⇒ tokens.switchMap(token ⇒ if (token) sharedQueue.take(1) else Observable.empty))`. Thank you, and I'm glad you had fun solving it.

Comment: Actually, the solution is very non-obvious to me the more I think about it. It seems that the main trick is in using `publish` to queue the elements internally. I'll have to contemplate that for some time..

Comment: So, I poked around a bit on the `publish` operator. there are a couple ways it works. The 'normal' way returns a `ConnectableObservable` that begins streaming when you connect to it. The `publish` used here with the selector is a bit different. It feeds in a (regular `Observable` version of the `Observable` it was chained from that can be subscribed to multiple times. It also manages requesting items from the subscription, which explains why we can switch between being subscribed without losing items. One caveat is you may need `onBackpressureBuffer` if `queue` produces items too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found one solution, inspired by Dave Sexton's comment. In the end I didn't use `zip` as I just couldn't figure a solution with it.

I basically implemented the turnstile as a state machine with three state variables: Whether it is locked or not, queue of elements waiting to pass through the turnstile, and the last element that has passed through the turnstile (these are collected in the end to produce the actual output).

Input to the state machine is a stream of transition requests, which is merged from two input streams: The stream of lock/unlock requests and the stream of elements to pass through the turnstile. I simply process the transitions with `scan`, and then `collect` the passed elements from the resulting states.

```scala
/** sample elements from queue through turnstile, one at a time
*
* @param queue source of elements to pass through the turnstile.
* @param turnstile For every `true` in the turnstile pass one element through from the queue
* @tparam T type of the elements
* @return the source of queue elements passing through the turnstile
*/
def queueThroughTurnstile[T](queue: Observable[T], turnstile: Observable[Boolean]): Observable[T] = {
  import scala.collection.immutable.Queue

  case class State(isOpen: Boolean, elementsInQueue: Queue[T], maybeLastEmittedElement: Option[T])
  sealed abstract class Transition
  case object Lock extends Transition
  case object Unlock extends Transition
  case class Element(element: T) extends Transition

  val initialState = State(isOpen = false, Queue.empty, None)

  queue.map(element ⇒ Element(element))
    .merge(turnstile map (unlock ⇒ if (unlock) Unlock else Lock))
    .scan(initialState) { case (State(isOpen, elementsInQueue, _), transition) ⇒ transition match {
    case Lock ⇒ State(isOpen = false, elementsInQueue, None)
    case Unlock ⇒ {
      if (elementsInQueue.isEmpty)
        State(isOpen = true, elementsInQueue, None)
      else {
        val (firstElement, newQueue) = elementsInQueue.dequeue
        State(isOpen = false, newQueue, Some(firstElement))
      }
    }
    case Element(newElement) ⇒ {
      if (isOpen) {
        if (elementsInQueue.isEmpty)
          State(isOpen = false, Queue.empty, Some(newElement))
        else {
          val (firstElement, newQueue) = elementsInQueue.dequeue
          State(isOpen = false, newQueue enqueue newElement, Some(firstElement))
        }  
      } else {
        State(isOpen = false, elementsInQueue enqueue newElement, None)
      }
    }
  }
  }.collect { case State(_, _, Some(lastEmittedElement)) ⇒ lastEmittedElement}
}
```