# Round-robin combining observables

Tags: scala, rx-java

I'm new to RxJava, and I've been trying to combine multiple observables in a round-robin way.

So, imagine you have three observables:

```
o1: --0---1------2--
o2: -4--56----------
o3: -------8---9----
```

Combining those in a round-robin way would give you something like:

```
r : --04---815-9-26-
```

What would be the best way to approach this?
Since it looks like RxJava, RxScala etc. pretty much share API, answer in any language should be fine. :)

Thanks,
Matija

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RxJava doesn't have such operator by default. The closest thing is using merge with well paced sources because it uses round-robin to collect values, but this property can't be relied upon. Why do you need this round-robin behavior?

The best bet is to implement this behavior manually. [Here is an example](https://gist.github.com/akarnokd/cd3917a08b8d79b235d5) without backpressure support.

Comment: Looks awesome! My approach after writing the question was to convert Observable to BlockingObservable, and then creating Iterator from BlockingObservable (all already implemented in RxJava). It seems this creates an Iterator which will block until there is an available element. What would be a reason this approach isn't good (except maybe error handling). From my point of view, the main reason could be that it's the complete opposite of reactive programming paradigm? But, my guess is it should be possible to create Observable which creates Iterator from all subjects, and cycles through them?

Comment: Your approach is blocking the sources unnecessarily.

Comment: a long shot, but can you imagine why this doesn't work if I have 4 Observables, and I merge 1. and 2. with MergeRoundRobin, and 3. and 4. with MergeRoundRobin concurrently. Seems like, at some point, InputSubscriber#onNext doesn't get called (even though Observable got a new value - I'm printing it)?

Comment: There could be some lost notification or state I didn't anticipate. Can you post a unit test that demonstrates this?

Answer (score 1):

There is an approach that is very simple to implement and does *almost* exactly what you want - just zip the three source observables, and than emit the three values from the zipped observable each time a new triplet arrives.

Translated to RxScala

```scala
val o1 = Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
val o2 = Observable.just(10, 20, 30)
val o3 = Observable.just(100, 200, 300)

val roundRobinSource = Observable
    .zip(Observable.just(o1, o2, o3))
    .flatMap(Observable.from[Int])

roundRobinSource.subscribe(println, println)
```

gives you

```
1
10
100
2
20
200
3
30
300
```

Which is precisely what you want.

The problem with this approach is that it will block until a value from each of the *three* sources arrives, but if your cool with that, I think this is by far the simplest solution. I'm curious, what is your use case?

## Update, Take #2

This is actually a fun question. Here is another take, that will trade one drawback for another.

```scala
import rx.lang.scala.{Subject, Observable}

val s1 = Subject[Int]()
val s2 = Subject[Int]()
val s3 = Subject[Int]()

val roundRobinSource3 = s1.publish(po1 ⇒ s2.publish(po2 ⇒ s3.publish(po3 ⇒ {
  def oneRound: Observable[Int] = po1.take(1) ++ po2.take(1) ++ po3.take(1)
  def all: Observable[Int] = oneRound ++ Observable.defer(all)
  all
})))

roundRobinSource3.subscribe(println, println, () ⇒ println("Completed"))

println("s1.onNext(1)")
s1.onNext(1)
println("s2.onNext(10)")
s2.onNext(10)
println("s3.onNext(100)")
s3.onNext(100)
println("s2.onNext(20)")
s2.onNext(20)
println("s1.onNext(2)")
s1.onNext(2)
println("s3.onNext(200)")
s3.onNext(200)
println("s1.onCompleted()")
s1.onCompleted()
println("s2.onCompleted()")
s2.onCompleted()
println("s3.onCompleted()")
s3.onCompleted()
println("Done...")
```

Gives you

```
s1.onNext(1)
1
s2.onNext(10)
10
s3.onNext(100)
100
s2.onNext(20)
s1.onNext(2)
2
20
s3.onNext(200)
200
s1.onCompleted()
s2.onCompleted()
s3.onCompleted()
Done...
```

It doesn't block, it round robins, but... it also doesn't complete :( You could make it complete in a stateful manner using a `takeUntil`, `Subject` and `doOnComplete` if you need it, though..

As for the mechanism, it uses the to me somehow mysterious behavior of `publish`, that keeps track of things already emitted. I have been originally pointed to it by @lopar when he answered my own questiong [Implementing a turnstile-like operator with RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797609/implementing-a-turnstile-like-operator-with-rxjava).

The behavior of `publish` is actually such a mystery to me, that I have posted a question about it here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/2775. If you are curious, you can follow it.

Comment: Yeah, as you said, it'll block until all a value arrives from all three sources, which doesn't fit my case. Still, I'll give you an upvote since I didn't explicitly mention that. As for the use case, I have a combination of Observable and Subject for stdout and stdin of the process, and I'm using the output of x-th process to calculate the input of the x+1-th process.

Comment: Matija, I'm not sure if SO informs on answer updates, thus this comment - I've found another approach on solving your question, you can have a look at it. Btw, could you please expand on your use case?