# Throwing data through narrow gate with Rx (Reactive Extensions)

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have a device with some send buffer, and i have to feed them with data avoiding buffer overflow.

I have two streams:

- one is flow of data (`IObservable<T>`)
- other is free buffer size (number of data pieces, wich I can throw to device) (`IObservable<int>`).

I need to combine it into one stream:

1. when data comes through first stream:

   1. if buffer is occupied (data in second stream = 0), data should be buffered
   2. if buffer is free (data in second stream = n > 0), first n (or less) pieces of data should be throwed to exit stream as `IList<T>`, other part of data should be buffered
2. when new free buffer size comes (if it > 0), first n (or less) pieces of data from buffer should be throwed to exit stream

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797609/implementing-a-turnstile-like-operator-with-rxjava could help you?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with `Observable.Buffer` and specify a count of `n`. Each time the buffer reaches `n` the data gets sent to the subscriber, which will be code to send it to the exit stream

```
var obs = Observable.Range(0,10)
                    .Buffer(4)
                    .Subscribe(x =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sending data...");

    // Simulate sending all data in x
    foreach (var element in x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
});
```