# Implementing resource queue in rx

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I have a hot observable `Observable<Resource> resources` that represents consumable resources and I want to queue up consumers `Action1<Resource>` for these resources.  A Resource can be used by at most 1 consumer.  It should not be used at all once a new value is pushed from `resources`.  If my consumers were also wrapped in a hot observable then the marble-diagram of what I'm after would be

```
--A--B--C--D--E--
----1----2--34---

----A----C--D-E--
----1----2--3-4--
```

I've managed a naive implementation using a `PublishSubject` and `zip` but this only works if each resource is consumed before a new resource is published (i.e. instead of the required sequence [A1, C2, D3, E4] this implementation will actually produce [A1, B2, C3, D4]).

This is my first attempt at using rx and I've had a play around with both `delay` and `join` but can't quite seem to get what I'm after.  I've also read that ideally `Subjects` should be avoided, but I can't see how else I would implement this.

```
public class ResourceQueue<Resource> {
    private final PublishSubject<Action1<Resource>> consumers = PublishSubject.create();

    public ResourceQueue(Observable<Resource> resources) {
        resources.zipWith(this.consumers, new Func2<Resource, Action1<Resource>, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call(Resource resource, Action1<Resource> consumer) {
                consumer.execute(resource);
                return null;
            }
        }).publish().connect();
    }

    public void queue(final Action1<Resource> consumer) {
        consumers.onNext(consumer);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve what I'm after?  Is there a more 'rx-y' approach to the solution?

Comment: Little late to the party :) I've had a problem that I think is similar in the nature here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797609/implementing-a-turnstile-like-operator-with-rxjava . Maybe it can help you to draw some inspiration..

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: changed [withLatesFrom](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) suggestion with [combineLatest](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html).

The only solution I can think of is to use [combineLatest](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) to get **all** the possible combinations, and **manually exclude** the ones that you do not need:

```
    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    final Observable<String> resources = Observable.create(s -> {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final List<Integer> sleepTimes = Arrays.asList(200, 200, 200, 200, 200);
                for (int i = 0; i < sleepTimes.size(); i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(sleepTimes.get(i));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    String valueOf = String.valueOf((char) (i + 97));
                    System.out.println("new resource " + valueOf);
                    s.onNext(valueOf);
                }
                s.onCompleted();
            }
        };
        executorService.submit(r);
    });
    final Observable<Integer> consumers = Observable.create(s -> {

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final List<Integer> sleepTimes = Arrays.asList(300, 400, 200, 0);
                for (int i = 0; i < sleepTimes.size(); i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(sleepTimes.get(i));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("new consumer " + (i + 1));
                    s.onNext(i + 1);
                }
                s.onCompleted();
            };
        };
        executorService.submit(r);

    });

    final LatestValues latestValues = new LatestValues();
    final Observable<String> combineLatest = Observable.combineLatest(consumers, resources, (c, r) -> {
        if (latestValues.alreadyProcessedAnyOf(c, r)) {
            return "";
        }
        System.out.println("consumer " + c + " will consume resource " + r);
        latestValues.updateWithValues(c, r);

        return c + "_" + r;
    });

    combineLatest.subscribe();

    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The class holding the latest consumers and resources.

```
static class LatestValues {
    Integer latestConsumer = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    String latestResource = "";

    public boolean alreadyProcessedAnyOf(Integer c, String r) {
        return latestConsumer.equals(c) || latestResource.equals(r);
    }

    public void updateWithValues(Integer c, String r) {
        latestConsumer = c;
        latestResource = r;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think so, no.  With the example above I want a result sequence of [A1, C2, D3, E4], but using withLatestFrom I'll get [A1, C2, D3, D4]

Comment: @tonyj444 right, I missed that. Then it's not so easy... I have updated the answer with `combineLatest`, although you are not going to like it.